# How to convert a CharField to Datetime Field in Python(Django)?

Tags: python, sql, django, datetime

I have a CharField in my model as well as my database. I want to convert this CharField column to real datetime Django format. I have this insert query like

```
test.objects.create(voice=m.voice, size=m.size, start_time=get_time.get('min_time'),)
```

I would like to create a function to solve it, but not sure how to do it. Please help.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to write a migration?

Comment: which field is char field in this new object? why can't you edit the model?

Comment: Actually i dont have a datetime field before. So I manually edited my model. What am doing here is querying to other table fields and put into one table(model). So one of the model has this subjected field as charfield other than datetime field. So I need to convert it to a datetime before I insert it to the new model(Table). Hope it clarifies.

Comment: It does not clarify :) Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think directly change the character field into datetime field is hard. Your need to do it one by one.

1. Create a new datetime column e.g. `start_datetime`
2. Create a script to convert the `start_time` from string into datetime object.
3. Edit all code that depend on `start_time`
4. Delete the `start_time` column

This is the example conversion from string to datetime code.

```
import time
for obj in Test.objects.all():
    obj.start_datetime = time.strptime(obj.start_time, "%d %b %y")
    obj.save()
```

You might want to read this python [time library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime).